# Python need for help for some beginner syntax

Tags: python, numpy, syntax

I just started with python and I have the following two lines I don't understand.

```
x = np.array(range(1,n+1))
Nx = np.array([(x < x_i).sum() for x_i in x]) / float(n)
```

More specifically, I don't understand what

```
np.array([(x < x_i).sum() for x_i in x])
```

exactly does?

Comment: do you know numpy ? if not then first read basic numpy from documentation.Dont jump on to complex equation directly.

Comment: I can create or reshape array in numpy. But the above command I don't get

Comment: Cut it to smaller pieces. First investigate `x < x_i` for various values of `x_i`. Then `(x < x_i).sum()`. Then... Of course, as pointed above, documentation might be very useful

Comment: Decompose to see what the parts do. For instance, for a small "n", do `for x_i in x: print(x, (x < x_i), (x < x_i).sum())`.  The new array is going to be the third thing printed in each line.

Comment: Remember, for numpy, something like `<` on an array processes the entire array, usually returning a new array.

Comment: So x<x_i returns an array of boolean with entry True if the corresponding entry in x is <x_i. Then sum sums up the 0/1 array, i.e. gives the number of values in x <x_i. I feel like the notation ... for ... is a bit weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) in python. The line

```
Nx = np.array([(x < x_i).sum() for x_i in x]) / float(n)
```

is essentially short-hand for

```
new_list = []
for x_i in x:
    new_elem = (x < x_i).sum()
    new_list.append(new_elem)

Nx = np.array(new_list) / float(n)
```

I think the for loop makes it fairly straightforward to understand what the list comprehension does. Use a debugger to step through the code and see what each line does if you're having trouble understanding the loop.

Now let's unpack what each part does.

With `numpy` arrays, you can perform element-wise comparison with the usual comparison operators. In each iteration, we have the array `x` and `x_i`, a scalar, is the `i`th element of the array.

- `(x < x_i)` performs an element-wise comparison on each element of `x` and returns a new array where each element is `True` or `False` depending on the result of the comparison operation. So essentially we have a `new_array` of booleans, such that the `p`th element `new_array[p] = x[p] < x_i`.
- `.sum()` calculates the sum of all the elements in this `new_array`. Because `True` evaluates to `1` and `False` to `0`, `.sum()` returns the number of `True` values in `new_array`. Which is another way to say it returns "the number of elements in `x` that are smaller than `x_i`"
- Now these values are put into the list by the list comprehension. So `new_list[i]` will be the number of elements in the array `x` that are less than `x[i]`.
- Finally, this is converted into a numpy array, and each element of this is divided by `float(n)`, which is the number of elements in `x`.

So, `Nx` is an array such that the `i`th element of `Nx` is the percentage of elements of `x` that are less than the `i`th element of `x`.

Comment: Thank you the reference "list comprehension" helped

Answer (score 1):

Just run each piece in a terminal and see what happens.

First, the `x` array is created with

```py
n = 5 # I added this such that n is defined
x = np.array(range(1,n+1))
```

This results in the `array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` array. But note that you should use `np.arange(1, n+1)` instead.

Now let's look at the second line. The argument of `np.array` is `[(x < x_i).sum() for x_i in x]`. This is a **list comprehension**. It's a nice syntax to create a list. We can read it like "for each element `x_i` in the list `x`, compute `(x < x_i).sum()`. But what is `(x < x_i).sum()`? We know that `x_i` is a single element, while `x` is the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. When you compare a NumPy array with an element like this you get a boolean array containing "True"s and "False"s. Then `sum()` will sum the elements (basically counting the number of "True"s). The result of this list comprehension is then converted into another array, whose elements are then divided by `n`.

Answer (score 1):

So for easy understanding let's break in to smaller chunks

```
np.array([(x < x_i).sum() for x_i in x])
```

**1.First Part**

```
for x_i in x
```

> represent each element in array x

**2nd part**

```
x < x_i
```

return a boolena value

for example:

```
x = np.array(range(1,9+1))
```

It creates a array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

then let's say i take xi as 9 then,

```
(x < 9)
```

returns a boolean value array

```
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False])
```

**3rd Part**

```
(x < x_i).sum()
```

sums all true value so when xi =9 sum is 8

**4th part**

```
np.array([(x < x_i).sum() for x_i in x])
```

it stores all value in a array Nx

Answer (score 0):

let's first break down

```
np.array([(x < x_i).sum() for x_i in x])
```

`(x < x_i)` : is a boolean expresion means that its result is false(or 0) or true(or 1).

`(x < x_i).sum()` : will give you the sum of the list.
example: suppose `x = array[1,2,3]`

1. The first case is `x_i = 1`, so (x < x_i) will give you `array([false,false,false])` because `x_i = 0 > 0` is **false**,`x_i = 0> 1`is **false** and the last one `x_i = 0 > 2` is **false**,
   and `sum(false,false,false) = sum(0,0,0) = 0`
2. the second case is `x_i = 2`, so so (x < x_i) will give you `array([ True, False, False])` so the `sum(true,false,false) = sum(1,0,0) = 1`
3. third case you'll find sum(true,true,false) = sum(1,1,0) = 2

therfore, `Nx = array([0,1,2])`